# Fastest way to calculate the sum of array elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the fastest way to calculate the sum of elements contained in an array.
I managed to do it using `eval()`, but i consider [eval as evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx).

```
var arr = [10,20,30,40,50];
console.log( eval( arr.join('+') ) ); //logs 150
```

### Is there a better way to do it other than using a `for loop` ?

I was thinking more about something like that, but it doesn't work:

```
var arr = [10,20,30,40,50];  

console.log( new Number( arr.join('+') ) ); //logs a Number Object  

console.log( new Number( arr.join('+') ).toString() ); //logs NaN
```

Comment: it will be the best if it will be `Math.sum` so we can do:
`Math.sum.apply(Math,arr)`  
but in my check there isn't

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If supported you can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method of `Array`

```
var arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

console.log(arr.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    return prev + cur;
}));
```

Comment: Is this the fastest method and why?

Comment: As @IvanCastellanos mentioned, the fastest way would be a plain old for loop, but `reduce` is shorter and much better and faster than `eval` :)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the reduce method. I however compared it on jsperf to the for loop, it seems that using the simple loop is faster.

Comment: Yeah, on my tests the `reduce` method was ~5 times slower than the for loop I use.

Comment: @Pierre On Google Apps Script (and therefore probably Google Chrome), as of October 20 2012, this method is the fastest out of the following: [eval join, for(v in arr), for (i<arr.len), while(i--), while(--i), reduce()]

Answer (score 18):

The best way is using a for loop. Is not the shortest, but is the best.

Comment: Since Array.join probably uses a loop internally anyway.

Comment: A loop is not much longer, and is certainly simpler to understand/maintain

Answer (score 0):

For loop is also better because arrays extend objects

```js
var arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   sum = sum + arr[i];
}
console.log("Sum of array = ",sum);
```